# What am I actually doing when calling Enumerable#reduce?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, whitespace, irb

Why can't I call [`Enumerable#reduce(sym)`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) without parentheses like the following?

```
>> [1, 2, 3].reduce :+
?>
```

While using parentheses results in this:

```
>> [1, 2, 3].reduce(:+)
=> 6
```

Am I accidentally calling `Enumerable#reduce {| memo, obj | block }` instead?

Furthermore, why does this happen?

```
>> [1, 2, 3].reduce &:+
?> ^C
>> [1, 2, 3].reduce(&:+)
=> 6
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That seems to be an error in IRb's parser. It works just fine if you try it in Pry, or on the commandline or in a file:

```
ruby -e"res = [1, 2, 3].reduce :+
p res"
# 6
```

Basically, IRb gets confused, thinks the `+` is a binary operator and is waiting for the second operand.

Comment: +1 I didn't know there was such a thing as Pry. Also, I didn't think to check it from a file. Thanks!

Comment: Note: I originally had `res = [1, 2, 3].reduce :+; p res` as an example, but it turns out that IRb can handle that just fine. It needs the newline to trigger the error.

Comment: I had tried `res = [1, 2, 3].reduce :+;` previously, but it just gave me the `?>` prompt. I didn't think to try typing `p res` afterward.

Comment: At the moment, Pry is basically a faster, better, more powerful, more featureful, better maintained, actively developed alternative to IRb. However, the *real* goal for it is to evolve into a Smalltalk/Lisp-style interactive development experience / IDE. It already has some interactive exploration capabilities, e.g. you can `cd` into an object and `ls` its instance variables, you can show the documentation or the source code for methods etc.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem the Ruby parser can't deal with that particular combination. Symbols have limitations, but `:+` and the like are some kind of special case that apparently requires brackets to be properly interpreted.

Notice if you try and evaluate `:+` by itself it doesn't parse. The same goes for other operators like `:*` and `:/` so something "magical" is going on here.

Comment: Ruby's parser handles this just fine. The problem is IRb's parser, which is basically a hodge-podge of `Regexp`s duct-taped together to parse something which hopefully but not quite exactly resembles the Ruby language. Pry uses YARV's, JRuby's or Rubinius's builtin parser instead, which is by definition always correct.

Comment: That would be a more reasonable explanation. I've never seen `irb` diverge from the Ruby interpreter that dramatically before, but then again, I'm a big fan of brackets.